# Can all BLE slaves receive a "trigger" message at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

We have 10 sensors (with analog to digital converter) with BLE as slaves, and would like all slaves to be triggered by the master so that all sensors can start sampling at the same time. Is it possible with BLE?

If not, what would be the smallest latency (or time skew) between two slaves getting triggered?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to first connect all 10 devices with a short connection interval (like 10 ms or whatever). Once that is done, you send write commands to all 10 of them at the same time. As long as the bluetooth controller can fit 10 enqueued packets, all of them will be sent in the next connection event for each BLE slave. Then your time skew will be within the connection interval.

Comment: Thanks, Emil. I'll try this.